# NetworkX coloring a node at runtime

Tags: python, graph, networkx

I have as an assigment to implement bfs and dfs graph traversal with visualization. To do that, I'm using NetworkX in Python. What I want to know is how to color a node at runtime? For example, when I am at a specific node in bfs/dfs, to set it's color to red or something. I know how to color different nodes of a graph, but not at runtime. I thinked that a possibility is to draw again and again the graph, but I'm sure that this is time consuming. Any sugestions?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

NetworkX draws static graphs but you can mark visited and unvisited edges with different colour and thickness to see the walk process.

```py
edgeSeq = [list of visited nodes]
nx.draw(G, pos, edge_color='gray',width=.2)
nx.draw(G, pos, edgelist = edgeSeq, edge_color='blue', width=2)
```

You may try [Cambridge Intelligence](https://cambridge-intelligence.com/methods-visualizing-dynamic-networks/) trial to work with the time bar features.